# BASH echo showing some unusual behaviour

Tags: bash

This is the simple command that is giving me problems -

```
echo hafsda sfsdfdsfs $ymn $ymx $range
```

The output of this command is coming -

```
 2.568 sfsdfdsfs 86.72
```

Where `ymn = 86.72` `ymx = 89.28` and `range = 2.56`. This only happens when I am using variables. The following command works fine -

```
echo hafsda sfsdfdsfs 1 2 $range
```

Also, the same command (the first one) works fine if I try running it directly in the terminal. This is only happening is a script. I also tried to use printf but encountered similar results.

I don't even understand what to google for to resolve this. I am unable to understand what is happening at all. So, what is happening here? Is this reproducible or is this just some error on my system, and if it is, what might be the problem?

Comment: Any chance `"hafsda"` is an alias or a command? Anyway try putting double-quotes around the argument list to echo.

Comment: Nope, it is just a symbol of my frustration, just a random string. And I don't have any alias like that. And I also tried with double-quotes around the whole argument list. Same result

Comment: You probably have a carriage return at the end of the input line or in the `$ymx` and `$range` variables – try `printf '%q\n' "$ymx" "$range"` to show control characters.

Comment: Yes, there is a carriage return after `$ymx`. I used `tr -d '\r'`. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your script probably has DOS-style CRLF line endings. I suspect you actually have `ymn="86.72\r"` `ymx="89.28\r"` and `range="2.56\r"`. You can test this in your script with

```
echo hafsda sfsdfdsfs $ymn $ymx $range | od -c
```

You can fix your script with `dos2unix` or `sed -i 's/\r$//` script.sh`.

Make sure you change the settings of your text editor do use unix line endings.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I had the variables just like that. It was an oversight on my part to directly use a DOSBOX generated text file as input in my script.

Comment: I used `tr -d '\r'` for the variables when they are fed into the script

Comment: You could use this to avoid having to spawn an external command: `"${var%$'\r'}"` which will expand the variable and remove a trailing carriage return.

Comment: Oh okay, great. Thank you.